# PyQt: Button hover description

Tags: python, button, pyqt, hover

I am using PyQt and I want to make a button that says "Hello", then when you hover over the button it says "Hello world". I'm not the best with PyQt, so I'm not sure on how to do this. Here is what I mean done in html:

[image]

Comment: `button.setToolTip('Hello World')`.

Comment: If you post so the code that shows button, it will be easier to help.

Comment: @ekhumoro your comment should the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Override enterEvent and leaveEvent.  [Example in c++](http://www.qtforum.org/article/27335/mouse-over-event-in-qpushbutton.html) illustrates concept.

Comment: OP said they're "not the best with PyQt", so it seems unlikely that that example is going to be much help to them...